# Storing an abstract class object from a map to abstract class reference

Tags: c++, dictionary, abstract-class

I am trying to implement the following method to get the bus corresponding to its name which is passed as a string to the method. Here AbstractBus is an abstract class which contains functionality of a bus. localBusses is a std::map

```
void getLocalBusByName(string& name, AbstractBus& bus) 
{
    bus =  localBusses.find(name)->second;
}
```

However, I am getting an error "no operator "=" matches these operands"
Can anyone explain what is wrong here and how can I correct it?

Comment: Could you post the error as reported by your compiler?

Comment: Is localBusses a map of String to AbstractBus or AbstractBus* (pointer to an AbstractBus)?

Comment: Please post the exact declaration of `localBusses`.

Comment: a map of string to AbstractBus

Comment: std::map<string, AbstractBus> localBusses;

Comment: Do you mean this: `std::map<std::string, AbstractBus*>`?

Comment: Can you post the declaration of AbstractBus? If this has any pure virtual functions then `std::map<std::string, AbstractBus>` should not compile.

Comment: std::map<string, AbstractBus> is not possible if AbstractBus is really abstract

Comment: what do you recommend, what is better
1.   std::map<string, AbstractBus*>  2. std::map<string, AbstractBus&>

Comment: @sufyansiddique It is not which is *better*, but what is *feasible*, the second one should not compile.

Comment: If `AbstractBus` has any derived classes use `std::map<std::string, AbstractBus*>`. Without seeing the declaration of `AbstractBus` and any associated class hierarchy it is difficult to provide more help.

Comment: thanks everyone for your help. I think i have understood the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code presents several problems

1. It does not handle the case when localBusses.find(...) doesn#t find a bus
2. You seem to want to return a reference to the found bus. You should remember that references are aliases and they can bind only when declared and remain immutable afterwards. That is you cannot re-bind a reference to another object
3. Following 2, the bus = ... attempts to call the assignment operator to assign the found bus to the one refered to by the reference. The assignment operator does not exist or is not accessible. This is good so since having an assignment operator in this context is a bad idea and if present it would probably lead to slicing if the AbstractBus class would be instantiable (non-abstract).

EDIT: I believe you either have:

```
typedef std::map<string, AbstractBus*> tBussesMap;
tBussesMap localBusses;
```

or AbstractBus is not really abstract (does not contain any pure methods) (despite its name)

In either case I assume however you have classes derived from AbstractBus. And getLocalBusByName has to provide for situations where no bus is found and avoid inadvertent slicing.

So you should write getLocalBusByName method in the lines of:

```
AbstractBus* 
getLocalBusByName( const string& name )
{
    tBussesMap::iterator it = localBusses.find(name);

    if ( it != localBusses.end() )
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

where localBusses is assumed to be of type:`std::map<string, AbstractBus*>` (the only viable way if AbstractBus is abstract)

Comment: @sufyan siddique You are wellcomed